# Laravel 5.1 acl roles and permission in frontend

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Here is my table structure for permissions, roles, and permission_role

permission:

id
name

roles:

id
name

permission_role:

role_id,
permission_id

Here permission_role is my pivot table.

In my frontend which i have setup something like this,

welcome.blade.php

```
  <form method="POST" action="/give/permission">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

      <select name="role" class="selectpicker" multiple data-max-options="2">
      @foreach($roles as $r)
      <option value="{{$r->id}}">{{$r->name}}</option>
      @endforeach
</select>
<div class="checkbox">
@foreach ($perm as $p)
    {!! Form::checkbox('p[]', $p->id, in_array($p->id, $all_data)) !!}
    {!! Form::label('permisssion', $p->name) !!}<br>
@endforeach
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="default">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

in my controller.php

```
public function postrolperm(Request $request,$id){
    $p = Role::find($id);
    $role = $request->role;
    //dd($input1);
    $permission = $request->p;
  //dd($input2);
  //
  //$role = Role::where("name", "admin")->get();

  if(isset($permission) && isset($role)){
    $role->givePermissionTo($permission);
    $role->save();
  }
  return redirect::back();
 }
```

role.php

```
public function givePermissionTo(Permission $permission)
    {
        return $this->permissions()->save($permission);
    }
```

I am not able to save the data into the pivot table.

I have tried in `php artisan tinker` with following commands:

```
 $role = Role::first(); //which gives me the first role with id of 1

    $role->givePermissionTo(Permission::first()); // it will save the first permission to the role.
```

What i am doing wrong in my controllers ?

Also to note that, that this routes works fine.

```
Route::get("/pivot", function(){
    $permission = new Permission;
    $permission->name = "can to";
    $permission->save();
    $role = new Role;
    $role->name = "admin2";
    $role->save();
    $role->givePermissionTo($permission);
    return "true";

});
```

Comment: Do a die dump, e.g. `dd(I am set)` inside the `if` within the controller function to make sure the role and permission are getting set from the request.

Comment: Yes..role and permission are getting set after die dump.

Comment: Call `$role->save();` after `$role->givePermissionTo($permission);`. Does that work?

Comment: I am also getting this error: Call to a member function givePermissionTo() on a non-object

Comment: No that doesnt work @MuyiwaOlu-Ogunleye

Comment: trying to recreate your problem, what does `$all_data` in your welcome view contain?

Comment: it shows you all the options of the roles,i mean all the roles

Comment: How does it differ to `$roles`? @Coold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is because you haven't created a `Role` and `Permission` object based on the `id`s passed back from the view. A working example is given below:

```
$role_id = $request->role;
$permission_ids = $request->p; // This comes back as an array.
if(isset($permission_ids) && isset($role_id)){
    $role_object = Role::where('id', $role_id)->firstOrFail();
    foreach ($permission_ids as $permission_id) {
        // loop through each permission id
        // find the corresponding permission object in the database
        $permission_object = Permission::where('id', $permission_id)->firstOrFail();

        // assign the object to the role
        $role_object->givePermissionTo($permission_object);
    }
    $role_object->save();
}
return Redirect::back()
```

Note that this will throw an exception if the role and permission passed back from the view don't correspond to a valid id in the database. Use`first()` instead of `firstOrFail()` if you want failures to be silent, i.e. not thrown an exception.

Make sure to add `use App\Role;` and `use App\Permission` to the top of your Controller file.

Your version fails due to the fact that you are trying to call the `givePermissionTo` function on a string representing the role id passed from the view - `$role`. You missed the step in between of getting the `Role` object from the database.

Curiously, you were on the right track with your `$p` variable, however you also needed to grab the corresponding `$permission` object from the database as shown in my example.

Comment: But now when i select multiple permission for single role, then i get the error like "No query results for model [App\Permission]". I have tried to do print_r($permission_id) and is_array($permission) in if statement. But could not insert those inside database.

Comment: I see the issue, I shall amend this when I get back to my computer .

Comment: Updated, please let me know if this fixes your issue. @Coold

Comment: yeah, that fixes the issue, thanks for this. But  i m getting the problem where i need to fetch all the roles with their permissions in the checkbox. Like i have done @foreach for all the roles and then $roles->permissions(). and i have belongsToMany relationship. How can i achieve this in blade. Any options out?

Comment: It's probably best to ask another question. If this fixed the original problem, please mark it as answered. Ask another question (relating to blade) and send me the link, I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: thanks , i have managed to update the blade where i can show the roles and their permissions, if i get the permission in updating which i think i must not get now,

Answer (score 1):

Did you added

```
use App\Role;
```

in controller.php file?

Comment: pass parameter "Request $request" to postrolperm function and also add "use Illuminate\Http\Request;" to the same controller file.